# Redirect from one address to another

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect $weird_address to $home_address, for example:

> $weird_address =  "https://homepage.com/?val=search&bname=&town=Yanziyan&country=China&ll=on&full=full&ss=1"
>
> $home_address = "https://homepage.com/"

I was trying a lot of different posibilities:

```
1. RewriteRule "https://homepage.com/?val=search&bname=&town=Yanziyan&country=China&ll=on&full=full&ss=1" 
"https://homepage.com/" [R=301,L]
2. RewriteRule "^/\?val=search\&bname=\&town=Yanziyan\&country=China\&ll=on\&full=full\&ss=1$" 
    "https://homepage.com/" [R=301,L]
3. RewriteRule "^(.*)China(.*)$" 
    "https://homepage.com/" [R=301,L]
4. Redirect 301 "https://homepage.com/?val=search&bname=&town=Yanziyan&country=China&ll=on&full=full&ss=1" 
"https://homepage.com/" "https://homepage.com/"
```

And much more.. But nothing has worked. My question is how to redirect that link? I've done research on the internet but I haven't found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly it is your want to, but the [syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is like:

```
Redirect /path/to/old.html http://www.example/path/to/new.html
Redirect /path/to/old.html /path/to/new.html
```

Do you get an error message?

Comment: I dont get error message and this doesnt do nothing `Redirect /?val=search&bname=&town=Yanziyan&country=China&ll=on&full=full&ss=1 https://homepage.com`